# How to decode JavaScript error from minified code

Tags: javascript, minify, source-maps

I have javascript errors from minified code logged on the server in a database. I have source maps for the minified code. How do I use those source maps to trace the error back to the original code.

I know I can do this in real time with the console, but these errors are from users submitting errors so I can't use the console to trace the error.